# table data not displaying as html using ko.js mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying my hand with knockout.js for a single page CRUD application, on almost everything it seems better than loading partial pages in to the view with ajax, one thing I'm having trouble with though, is rendering a textarea in parsed html, instead I get all the tags `<p>` etc.

When I was using Razor/C# I would just use `@Html.Raw(Model.Details)` however now I'm using `<td data-bind="text: Details"></td>`.

I have tried `<td>@Html.Raw(new { @data_bind="text: Details" })</td>` but no luck.

What would be the best way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have HTML in your viewmodel you need the [`html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) to display it:

> The `html` binding causes the associated DOM element to display the HTML
>   specified by your parameter.
>
> Typically this is useful when values in your view model are actually
>   strings of HTML markup that you want to render.

So your code should look like this:

```
<td data-bind="html: Details"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `html` binding for this.
Look it up here in their very good [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html).

So in your html element, it should be like this.

```
<td data-bind="html: Details"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, had missed the documentation.